# Navigator series in Highstock (highcharts-ng)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, navigator, highcharts-ng

I have a Highstock chart. I use highcharts-ng for that. After I remove old serie and add new one, serie in navigator doesn't update. It's not so necessary to have this miniature of chart in navigator, I can set it's opacity and I don't see it, but I need to have the proper range after changing serie. And the range doesn't update too. Here is screencast:

http://videobam.com/jXwOC

Here is my navigator configuration:

```
    navigator:
      adaptToUpdatedData: true
      series:
        data: []
      xAxis:
        labels:
          style:
            fontSize: '14px'
            fontWeight: 'bold'
      maskFill: 'rgba(0, 165, 211, 0.05)'
      enabled: true
      series:
        # lineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
        # fillColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
        lineColor: '#00a5d3'
        fillColor:
          linearGradient : {  
            x1 : 0, 
            y1 : 0, 
            x2 : 0, 
            y2 : 1 
          }, 
          stops : [[0, '#95d7e7'], [1, '#ffffff']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigator is always bind to the first series or the series according to ID. So instead of removing series, use [`series.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.update) - that will update series with all required options, and connection will be working.

Comment: I tried to use update, but `$scope.chartConfig.series.update` is `undefined`. I don't know how to actually do this using `highcharts-ng`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that plugin. I guess it should be enough to update just required options in `config.series[index]` and chart should be redrawn.

Comment: But I have different number of series (sometimes one, sometimes two), so what I'm doing right now is setting `$scope.chartConfig.series.length = 0` and after this `$scope.chartConfig.series.push(serie)`.

Comment: I see no other solution than using `$scope.chartConfig.series[0] = serie` for existing series and `$scope.chartConfig.series.push(serie)` for new series. But, as I said, I'm not familiar with highcharts-ng, I assume that after looking into the source code.